# How do you always include values in a route by default?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am setting some values in a route and can't figure out how to permanently make the route use these values.

For example i have this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{corpID}/{locationID}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { corpID = "Test", locationID = 2, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

I'd like the corpID and LocationID to always be in the route so i can go to say `/Controller/Action` without having to always include `CorpID/LocationID/Controller/Action`

Comment: You would need the `corpID`/`locationID` to come after the `controller`/`action` in your route, otherwise the first two route values supplied will always match to `corpID`/`locationID` and their defaults will be ignored.

Comment: Would I always have to have them in the URL?

Comment: if you want `corpID/locationID` default then why you add it before the controller,you can add it after action .then only routing not confuse whether it `corpID/locationID` or controller it always consider first controller then action and then if you define `corpID/locationID` or take default one